# Java Calendar.getTimeInMillis

Tags: java, calendar

I'm trying to convert String timestamps of the form "201110250830" (yyyyMMddhhmm) to a number of milliseconds (a long). I'm using the following code:

```
Calendar t = Calendar.getInstance();
         t.set(Integer.parseInt(ts.substring(0,4)),
               Integer.parseInt(ts.substring(4,6)) - 1, // month is 0 based!
               Integer.parseInt(ts.substring(6,8)),
               Integer.parseInt(ts.substring(8,10)),
               Integer.parseInt(ts.substring(10,12)),
               0);
return t.getTimeInMillis();
```

However, I sometimes get an off by a few milliseconds discrepancy. For example:

```
long t1 = timestampToLong("201110250830");
long t2 = timestampToLong("201110250831");
assertEquals(60*1000, t2 - t1);
```

*sometimes* gives me:

```
Got exception: java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<60000> but was:<60001>
```

I checked the doc, but I couldn't find anything relevant. Any idea? (looks like a good day, I'm going to learn something here! :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call `t.clear()` before calling `set()`.

Welcome to the world of Java time/date handling.

Answer (score 4):

you could using DateFormat like this.

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm");
Date ins = df.parse("201110250830");
long ts = ins.getTime();
```